# 502 DNS lookup failed error when using SharePoint 2013 CSOM

Tags: 2013, client-object-model

I am facing an issue while using CSOM in SharePoint 2013. I have configured an alternate access mapping for our site to run on `http://mycustomdoamin.net/` The site is running fine and I am able to see the pages.

Now I am trying to use CSOM to get the current SP context and execute a query. At that point, I am getting error:

> Unexpected data from server

On investigating with Fiddler, I found that SharePoint is making a call to `http://mycustomdoamin/_api/contextinfo`.

Note that the above is NOT the FQDN that I have configured my site for. It is missing the .net domain extension. Consequently, I am getting a 502 DNS lookup failed error.

The same script works fine when running without the mapping (e.g. on `http://ServerName` ). I have also tried setting up hosts file entry for the domain but that too doesn’t work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but in my case I'm using Office365 and with and with a site collection that isn't is the root of sitecollection (`/sites/mysite`).

I'm not sure about the problem but when I whatch the variable with the `SP.ClientContext.get_current()` value I have showed that the "`$u_0`" property has the value "`https://mysubscription.sharepoint"` so when CSOM try to make the calls it has the same error.

I have founded two solutions that dependeds of your solutions:

The first option, set the "`$u_0`" property before you call the executeQueryAsync method. For example:

```
function FixContext(Context) {
if (Context.$u_0.indexOf(".sharepoint") > 0)
    if (Context.$u_0.indexOf(".com") < 0)
        Context.$u_0 += ".com";

return Context;}
```

The second option consist on use the "`_spPageContextInfo`" variable:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("InitializeObjects_fromPagecontextInfo");

function InitializeObjects_fromPagecontextInfo() {
RelativeSiteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;}
```